# CSS and/or jQuery to add little clickable image to multiple select list

Tags: jquery, css, list, multiple-select

I have a select list with multiple rows, and I want it to have a small X image at the end of each row so it deletes that row.
Any idea how I can do that through CSS or jQuery or something?? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean an actual `<select>` or something you're calling a "select list"?  We'll need the markup in the second case, in the first...no, you can't do this.

Comment: You going to need to 'roll your own' select box for this.

Comment: `<select multiple="multiple">` actually.

Answer (score 0):

Create one div (your "drop-down button") and another hidden div for the container (your "menu" that contains all those rows with images), assign onClick event to the drop-down, so when it's clicked you will toggle your menu.

Comment: using html, css and javascript.

Comment: tutorial? where can i see what you are saying so i can have a general idea and do it.

Comment: here is a good example http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a jQuery plugin like this one: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dropdownReplacement

It allows you to do a lot more with textbox and select fields in terms of styling than a traditional HTML select/option fields would allow for.